# Find the next max occurrence based on a previous occurrence of a different value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to capture Start and End times of a batch process from a log table with a single timestamp column. Start and End times of the process can be identified by Step Definition, however, the batch process may run into more than one day sometimes like below. Also, sometimes the process may be restarted if any failures, resulting into multiple "Start" steps

For. e.g

| LOG_TIME | STEP_DETAIL |
| --- | --- |
| 01/10/2023 10:00 | Process Start |
| 01/10/2023 18:00 | Process Finish |
| 02/10/2023 10:00 | Process Start |
| 02/10/2023 15:00 | Process Start |
| 02/10/2023 18:00 | Process Start |
| 03/10/2023 01:00 | Process Finish |
| 03/10/2023 10:00 | Process Start |
| 03/10/2023 13:00 | Process Start |
| 03/10/2023 18:00 | Process Finish |

The results I expect to be shown as

| Batch Run Date | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2023 | 01/10/2023 10:00 | 01/10/2023 18:00 |
| 02/10/2023 | 02/10/2023 18:00 | 03/10/2023 01:00 |
| 03/10/2023 | 03/10/2023 13:00 | 03/10/2023 18:00 |

I tried using `MAX()` with a `CASE` logic in it, however, when it rolls over to next day, I have a trouble fetching the value

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(LOG_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') LOG_DATE, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN STEP_DETAIL = 'Process Start' THEN TO_TIMESTAMP(LOG_DATE) END) AS START_TIME, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN STEP_DETAIL = 'Process Finish' THEN TO_TIMESTAMP(LOG_DATE) END) AS END_TIME 
FROM 
    SAMPLE 
GROUP BY 
    TO_DATE(LOG_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') 
ORDER BY 
    TO_DATE(LOG_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `group by` on finish time and `self join` as follows:

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(MAX(STRT.LOG_TIME)) AS BATCH_RUN_DATE, 
    MAX(STRT.LOG_TIME) AS START_TIME, 
    FNSH.LOG_TIME AS END_TIME
FROM TEST STRT
JOIN TEST FNSH ON STRT.LOG_TIME <= FNSH.LOG_TIME
 WHERE
        STRT.STEP_DETAIL = 'S'
       AND FNSH.STEP_DETAIL = 'F'
 GROUP BY
    FNSH.LOG_TIME
 ORDER BY BATCH_RUN_DATE;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QavevKEU)

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS batch_run_date,
       start_time,
       finish_time
FROM   sample
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY log_time
  MEASURES
    strt.log_time AS start_time,
    fnsh.log_time AS finish_time
  PATTERN (strt fnsh)
  DEFINE
    strt AS step_detail = 'Process Start',
    fnsh AS step_detail = 'Process Finish'
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample (LOG_TIME, STEP_DETAIL) AS
SELECT DATE '2023-10-01' + INTERVAL '10' HOUR, 'Process Start'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-01' + INTERVAL '18' HOUR, 'Process Finish' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-02' + INTERVAL '10' HOUR, 'Process Start'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-02' + INTERVAL '15' HOUR, 'Process Start'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-02' + INTERVAL '18' HOUR, 'Process Start'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-03' + INTERVAL '01' HOUR, 'Process Finish' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-03' + INTERVAL '10' HOUR, 'Process Start'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-03' + INTERVAL '13' HOUR, 'Process Start'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-10-03' + INTERVAL '18' HOUR, 'Process Finish' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| BATCH_RUN_DATE | START_TIME | FINISH_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-01 10:00:00 | 2023-10-01 18:00:00 |
| 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-02 18:00:00 | 2023-10-03 01:00:00 |
| 2023-10-03 | 2023-10-03 13:00:00 | 2023-10-03 18:00:00 |

Or, if you want to match all the `Process start` times and have `batch_run_start` as the first start time and `start_time` as the successful start time that corresponds to a finish time then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   sample
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY log_time
  MEASURES
    FIRST(strt.log_time) AS batch_run_date,
    LAST(strt.log_time) AS start_time,
    fnsh.log_time AS finish_time
  PATTERN (strt+ fnsh)
  DEFINE
    strt AS step_detail = 'Process Start',
    fnsh AS step_detail = 'Process Finish'
)
```

Which outputs:

| BATCH_RUN_DATE | START_TIME | FINISH_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 10:00:00 | 2023-10-01 10:00:00 | 2023-10-01 18:00:00 |
| 2023-10-02 10:00:00 | 2023-10-02 18:00:00 | 2023-10-03 01:00:00 |
| 2023-10-03 10:00:00 | 2023-10-03 13:00:00 | 2023-10-03 18:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/isFCb_mb)